# i am getting error like this in angular js Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having a problem with Angular JS receiving an error: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]. My JS-file looks

this is my app js

```
var app = angular.module(' myApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider

.state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
    controller: 'homeCtrl'
    });
otherwise('/home');
}]);
```

this is my index page

```
 <div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-view></div>
 </div>
 
 <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/controller.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/app.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/directives.js"></script>
```

this is my controller js

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);                                  
  app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) 
  {
        $scope.names = [{nickname:'n',fullname:'nakama'}];
  });
```

this is my home page

```
 <div>
 <ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in names">
     {{x.nickname + '<-means->' + x.fullname}}
  </li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: load your `app.js` files before your `controller.js`

Comment: thanks dude CozyAzure it's work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load your `app.js` before your `controller.js`

```
 <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
 <!--Load this first-->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/app.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/controller.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/directives.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
```

It means you want start a new module.
change it to

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');
```

note, the [] has been removed;

This way angular returns the existing myApp module

Also:

move app.js before controller.js in your html

Answer (score 0):

You need to load `app.js` before than `controller.js`

and Inside controller file, do not instatiate same module again

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]); // remove [] from here.
```

Hope it helps you.

Cheers